# hex value not writing to image

Tags: c#, rtf, memorystream

I am trying to build a larger tool that will take hex strings from .RTF format and dump them to files. This attempt at writing to file from a memory stream is throwing an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' on ReadTimeout and WriteTimeout. I'm a bit in over my head I believe.

the code that I am working with is:

```
 private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

            // Image hex data
            string hexImgData = @"FFD8FFE000104A46494600010200006400640000FFFFD9";

            // Call function to Convert the hex data to byte array
            byte[] newByte = ToByteArray(hexImgData);
            MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(newByte);

            // Save the memorystream to file
            Image image = Image.FromStream(memStream, false, false);

                image.Save(@"C:\img.jpg");
            memStream.Close();
            image.Dispose();
    }

    // Function converts hex data into byte array
    public static byte[] ToByteArray(String HexString)
    {
        int NumberChars = HexString.Length;

        byte[] bytes = new byte[NumberChars / 2];

        for (int i = 0; i < NumberChars; i += 2)
        {
            bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(HexString.Substring(i, 2), 16);
        }
        return bytes;
    }

}
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Its not a valid jpg image...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is take a hex string and dump it to a file, there's no need to overcomplicate it by wrapping it in a `MemoryStream` and then an `Image`. Just write the bytes directly to a file:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\img.jpg", newByte);
```

The reason you get the error is as Ron commented; the hex string you gave does not form a valid JPEG image.

Comment: I suppose I should expand my question. I am trying to convert a hex string from rtf files into a image that would get programatically dropped into a Word template via DocIO from syncfusion. This is a classic conversion problem and I feel like maybe what I was planning all-together was overcomplicating things to begin with...

Comment: I am going to mark yours as the answer because it works for what I asked. I will start a new question about syncfusion DocIO and rtf.